# XMLHttpRequest calls do not include If-Modified-Since header

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

I have a simple caching mechanism on the server, which sets the approriate `Last-Modified` header and also reacts to the `If-Modified-Since` header. A sample of the response headers is:

```
Date: Tue, 17 Mar 2015 20:40:14 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 16 Mar 2015 09:47:28 GMT
```

After I have navigated to the page once, the browser includes and `If-Modified-Since` header in the request and the sever correctly responds with a 304 status.

However, when I perform the request using jQuery ( and the behaviour remains for a simple XMLHttpRequest ) the `If-Modified-Since` header is not sent.

The simplest code to reproduce this is:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("get", "http://localhost/some/page.html", true);
xhr.send();
```

This sort of code always generates a 200 response, even though it was previously cached. I've observed this in Firefox 36 and Chromium 41.

Why isn't the `If-Modified-Since` header included in XMLHttpRequest-originated calls?

Comment: So in other words, this has nothing to do with jQuery right? it still happens when you drop down to XMLHttpRequest? I would have left jQuery out of the question since you've already confirmed it to be irrelevant.

Comment: @KevinB - right, this has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: Here's an article that suggests adding an Expires Header: http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/08/07/ajax-caching-two-important-facts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this was user error as I can't reproduce it anymore.